# Errors with arrays in GDB (written in C)

Tags: c, arrays, debugging

I'm trying to find the memory locations of the elements of an array. The function is basically this (in C):

```
int function(struct MyStruct *s)
{
    char myArray[16];

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    gets(myArray);
    return strcasecmp(s->a,guess);
}
```

According to GDB guides online I should be able to do "x myArray" or "x myArray[0]" or "p myArray" or "p myArray[0]" to see the elements or memory locations. I set up breakpoints at function and gets (and continued until the gets breakpoint), but when I tried the GDB commands, I got "no such file." I also tried "b 15" to set a breakpoint at the array and "b 16." but I still got the same error. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: We have just fired our entire guessing department. Please post an entire transcript of your GDB session verbatim.

Comment: I'm not at the computer I was using anymore, but I basically did "break main, break function, break gets, break 15 (which didn't work), break 16 (which didn't work), run, s (until I reach the gets breakpoint), x myArray, x myArray[0], p myArray, p myArray[0]"

Comment: I was actually more interested in GDB messages. Anyway, it looks like you have a program compiled without debugging information.

Comment: The teacher gave us the binary and said to run it from that since debugging information would change memory addresses.

Comment: If you don't have symbolic debugging information, you cannot use symbolic debugging functionality of GDB (obviously). The GDB commands you have tried do not apply.

Comment: How would I find the values I need without the debugging information? It's necessary for the assignment.

Comment: I don't know why your teacher want you to debug a program that lacks debugging information. Perhaps you are in the assembly hacking class?

Comment: No. It's just a regular C and assembly class. (Not sure if you're making a joke since you made one earlier)

Comment: Would I be able to find the answer from "disas function"?

Comment: I don't know. You might have to examine registers and raw memory by address, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "break main, break function, break gets, break 15 (which didn't work), break 16 (which didn't work), run, s (until I reach the gets breakpoint), x myArray, x myArray[0], p myArray, p myArray[0]"

You are doing it *wrong*.

When you hit the `gets` breakpoint, you are stopped *inside* `gets`.

In there, the `myArray` variable is not visible -- it's inside `function`, not inside `gets`.

You can't `break 15` while inside `gets` either, because you don't have debug info for `libc` (which is where `gets` is implemented).

What you want to do is `finish` from the breakpoint in `gets` (which will bring you back into `function`). *Now* you should be able to look at `myArray`, or `break 15`, etc.